# ASP.NET Converting repeater item to the textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, .net

I'm trying to convert item repeaters to the text boxes and check all text boxes if all of them are empty but i get this error in line 3.

```
System.InvalidCastException

            int check = 0;
            foreach (RepeaterItem item in searchResultRepeater.Items)
            {
                if (item.Controls.Count > 0 && item.Controls[0] is ITextControl)
                {
                    if (((TextBox)item.Controls[0]).Text == "") // Exception here
                    {
                        check = 0;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        check = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

How can i fix this ? Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it

```
        int check = 0;

        foreach (RepeaterItem item in searchResultRepeater.Items)
        {
            TextBox txt = (TextBox)item.FindControl("yourTextBoxName");

            if (txt.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                check = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                check = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
```